# Moving const and overloaded Universal Reference in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am watching Scott Meyer's video "The Universal Reference/Overloading Collision Conundrum", where he gives an example of what not to do:

```
class MessedUp {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void doWork(const T& param) { std::cout << "doWork(const T& param)" << std::endl; }

    template<typename T>
    void doWork(T&& param) { std::cout << "doWork(T&& param)" << std::endl; }

};

.... //somewhere in the main

MessedUp m;
int w = 10;
const int cw = 20;

m.doWork(cw); // calls doWork(const T& param) as expected 
m.doWork(std::move(cw)); // Calls doWork(T&& param)
```

I am curious as to why compiler chose `doWork(T&& param)` rather than `doWork(const T& param)` during Template Overload resolution. As far as I know, `const` objects can't be moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After template type deduction and substitution, the two overloads become:

```
//template<typename T>
void doWork(const int& param) { std::cout << "doWork(const T& param)" << std::endl; }

//template<typename T>
void doWork(const int&& param) { std::cout << "doWork(T&& param)" << std::endl; }
```

Note how `T` in the second overload has been deduced to `const int`.

Now, what happens is normal overload resolution: We compare the implicit conversion sequences required to convert the argument expression `std::move(cw)` (which is an xvalue of type `const int`) to the parameter types. Both rank as Exact Matches, so we have to look at the tie-breakers in [over.ics.rank]/3 and compare the two implicit conversion sequences `S1` and `S2` (a reference binding here is a conversion sequence):

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>   [...]
>
> - `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings [...], and `S1` binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference.

As an xvalue *is* an rvalue (and a glvalue), this point applies, and the second overload is chosen.

Comment: The actual explanation should then be something like *"an rvalue reference binds stronger to an rvalue than a (const) lvalue reference does"*, and `std::move(cw)` produces an rvalue.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` does not mean move, it means rvalue reference.  rvalue references will only bind to temporary(anonymous) objects, or objects cast to appear to be temporary objects by functions like `std::move` or `std::forward`, or objects automatically marked by the compiler to be temporary like locals returned from function on simple `return X;` lines.

You can have an rvalue reference to a `const` object.  When this happens, you cannot move (unless `mutable` state can be moved), but it is still an rvalue reference.

Now, `T&&` can bind to an lvalue reference if `T` is an lvalue reference, so in type deduction context `T&&` can be called a universal reference.  So one of the real problems with the above design is that `m.doWork(w)` will also bind to `T&&` with `T=int&`.

In overload resolution, a function that takes a `template<typename T> void foo(T&&)` with `T=foo&` be considered to be a worse match than `template<typename T> void foo(T&)` with `T=foo` if everything else is equal: but in your case, there is no `T` such that `foo(T const&)` is a `foo(T const&&)`.

Comment: "You can have an rvalue reference to a const object", no, you can't.

Comment: "Now, `T&&` can bind to an lvalue reference if `T` is a reference" I'd say perhaps, *`T&&` can bind to an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference*, but this isn't the whole story of course, as there's a special type deduction rule that makes "universal references" possible.

Comment: @mfontanini: Yes, you can, if the object is a const r-value.

Comment: A direct reference binding is considered an Exact Match, see [over.ics.ref]/1

Comment: @DyP I love standardese.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` are useful to determine temporary rvalues from non-rvalue. So, you can steal the resource safely.

When you use `std::move` it casts the type to a rvalue and compiler will uses `&&` overload.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that `doWork(T&& param)` is being called with `T = const int`, because that is a perfect match (instead of a conversion to lvalue).

If you had trued to move the object, it would indeed have failed because const objects can't be moved.

Comment: are you sure it is not `T = const int&` ?

Comment: Where's the conversion to an lvalue necessary?